# Что-то не так с выборкой данных php + mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Вот что я пишу, поле такое есть,но почему-то не находит:

```
$forpost = $_POST['email'];
$quer = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = \'"$forpost"\'';
$findemail = $db->query($quer);
```

Помогите пожалуйста, может что-то не так с `\'"$forpost"\''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одинарных кавычках не выполняется подстановка данных. Советую почитать об этом, чтобы не возникало ошибок в дальнейшем ([первая ссылка в выдаче гугла](http://profiphp.ru/useful/single_double_quotes.html)).

Исправьте $quer следующим образом и все будет работать: `` $quer = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$forpost'"; ``

Правда ко всему прочему, вариант представленный вами не исключает возможности sql-инъекции, поэтому, я бы еще экранировал подставляемые значения, а то и вовсе использовал [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

В вашем случае можно экранировать кавычки при помощи `$db->escape_string($_POST['email'])`

Comment: Спасибо Большое! Всё работает отлично!

Comment: Дополнил пост информацией о экранировании символов и ссылкой на статью про разницу между кавычками в PHP. Думаю, будет полезно.